# why are there Nan values in Bokeh Datatable?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I've written a couple functions to create a datatable based on input Dataframe. For some reason the values get lost and the output only shows nan values.

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, DataRange1d\
,Plot, LinearAxis, Grid,Label,LabelSet,HoverTool,NumeralTickFormatter
from bokeh.models.glyphs import HBar
from bokeh.io import curdoc, show, output_file
from bokeh.models.layouts import Column
from bokeh.resources import INLINE
import bokeh.io
bokeh.io.output_notebook() 
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.sampledata.commits import data
from bokeh.transform import jitter
from bokeh.models.widgets import Panel, Tabs
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox, Column
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, DateFormatter, TableColumn,NumberFormatter,Panel, Tabs

def create_data_source(DF):
    columns = []
    DF = DF.reset_index().set_index('ServicedOn').T
    for item in DF:
        columns.append(TableColumn(field=items,
                                    title=item,
                                    width = 1000,
                                    formatter=NumberFormatter(format='0,0')))
    source = DF.drop('Year').to_dict(orient= 'list')
    return (source,columns)
def Create_data_table(DF,year):
        width = 1000
        source, columns = create_data_source(DF.loc[DF.index == str(year)])
        if 3 > len(source) < 7:
            width = 500
        elif len(source) < 3:
            width = 300
        Data_table = ( DataTable(columns = columns,source=ColumnDataSource(source),
                  height = 100, width = width,row_headers= False) )
        return (Panel(child=Data_table, title=str(year)))
show(Tabs(tabs = [Create_data_table(PD2,2016)]))
```

[image]
Sample Dataframe is as such:

```
    ServicedOn  amount_spent
Year        
2016    October 31302
2016    November    5750
2016    December    0
```

I've gone through the code but couldn't understand where the value is getting lost. Any Idea ?

Comment: I have many error while running your code : items instead of item, DF.loc[DF.index == str(year)] ... Please could you share a runnable code so I can test and find what's wrong ?

Comment: lol I think that was the error(items). I must not have not seen it.

Comment: Thanks a lot louc, just please post the error as your answer so I can upvote it !

Comment: glad to be useful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has errors: itemS instead of item

```
# your code : columns.append(TableColumn(field=items, title=item [...]
columns.append(TableColumn(field=item, title=item [...]
```

Maybe it's the cause : bokeh can't find the data

Comment: Yeah, that was it! Bokeh couldn't find the data, but never threw an error.